# In jQuery, is the selector $('[id=foo]') less efficient than $('#foo')?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

In jQuery, is the selector **$('[id=foo]')** less efficient than **$('#foo')**?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

- short and easy: **YES** !
- long story (still short actually)

  ```
   $('[id=foo]')
  ```

  uses Sizzle (css query engine) to select the element whereas

  ```
   $('#foo')
  ```

  directly calls `getElementById`.

To have a really long story, here we go: `$('[id=foo]')` is a synonym for `$('*:[id=foo]')` which uses the universal selector. That means, it querys **ALL** nodes within your markup and then looks which of those have the `id === foo` (which then hopefully will only match one element, IDs = unique). That of course, is costly, pretty costly. And that is why you never ever ever ever should write a selector like this!
**Always** fully qualify this if possible, like `$('span:[id=foo]')`

Comment: Ahh heres a sub-question for you then jAndy - is `$('span:[id=foo]')` just longhand for `$(span#foo)` or a different selector altogether?

Comment: @HurnsMobile: Not at all. `$('span:[id=foo]')`. I actually would recommend to have a look over the jQuery init code here. jQuery does parse some selector expressions to a direct call of `getElementById` or `getElementsByTagName`, I think `$(span#foo)` is one of those. So it's definatly faster than `$('span:[id=foo]')`. That expression will go into Sizzle and that obviously takes longer than one of the above mentioned methods.

Comment: Very informative, thanks a lot. The reason I was considering using something besides $("#foo") to target an id is because the id I was targeting had a period in it, which is obviously problematic as jQuery would interpret this as an id and a class. So by using $("[id=Address.State]"), for example, I could get around the issue. Another way to get around it is to double escape the period as in $("#Address\\.State"), but I thought the double escape might be less readable. However, given the efficiency loss you pointed out, I'd probably use that anyway.

Answer (score 1):

yeah,.

The fastest selector in jQuery is the ID selector $('#foo')  because it maps directly to a native JavaScript method, getElementById()